# In my loop unless I constantly output I cant close my window

Tags: java, window

I am dividing my program into to sections. A core library and and the application.
In the library I have a custom Window class and it won't respond to me closing it unless I'm constantly outputting a string.

BTW Window extends frame.

For Example:

```
private static Window window;

public static void init()
{

    Engine.init();

    window = new Window(640, 480, "Flux Engine");
    window.setVisible(true);

    while(!window.isCloseRequested())
    {

        //System.out.println("ds");
        window.update();

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    init();

}
```

This won't respond to me hitting the close button but if I uncomment the print statement it will.

Look at the update method

```
public void update()
{

    if(closeRequested) {destroy();}

}

public void destroy()
{

    setVisible(false);
    dispose();
    System.out.println("Window Destroyed.");

}
```

Comment: Most GUI frameworks are single threaded, meaning if you use a `loop` of somekind, like you have, it can block it's main thread, preventing it from processing new events and making your program become unresponsive.  It "looks" like you're using Swing, so you might like to have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4CS-2T7UxqrRlF5eEx6aV9nX2c  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4CS-2T7UxqrRzJ4Y1NiWk5YM2c ignore the engine.init

Answer (score 0):

Well, in order for your program to not take up 100% cpu and also listen on other commands, I would suggest you put a wait or a sleep statement inside that loop. Also, if you want your program to do something outside the loop, put it in a separate thread: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: Well I debugged some more and learned that its not program usage its just not calling the update method